Is my stepfather's other wife my mahram?
My biological mother married 2nd time(she died after 2 months of marriage). And now my step father passed away, Now I live with my Step father's 1st wife. Is she  still consider mahram(mom) for me. Is living under same apartment and touching her haram for me?

This question is similar to: Who are the women that a man is forbidden to marry?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I didn't understand that because she is  the wife of my step father, both are not biological. Please answer this in simple words.

She is not your mahram.


4 Allah has not made for a man two hearts in his interior. And He has not made your wives whom you declare unlawful your mothers. And he has not made your adopted sons your sons. That is your saying by your mouths, but Allah says the truth, and He guides to the way.
5 Call them by their fathers; it is more just in the sight of Allah . But if you do not know their fathers - then they are your brothers in religion and those entrusted to you. And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful.
— Al-'Ahzab 4-5

In Islam, a stepfather/stepson relationship is not considered the same as a true father/son relationship. Therefore his wife — your stepmother — is not the wife of your father, and she does not fall under the mahram category. As far as the laws of Islam are concerned, she is considered the same as any other unrelated married woman.
